# Unity - Camera Moving Vertical

Tags: unity, c#, camera

So I want to make a smooth transition with the camera from point A to point B while keeping direction and rotation.

My current approach is using Vector3.Lerp :

```
using UnityEngine;
 
public class CameraMoveVertical : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float cameraSpeed = 0.125f;
 
    public void moveCamera()
    {
        Vector3 lerpPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+50, transform.position.z), cameraSpeed);
        transform.position = lerpPosition;
    }
}
```

The camera does move but the movement is instant. Any way to make it a smooth transition?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script by itself won't do anything, since the `moveCamera()` function is never called. Are you calling `moveCamera` from another script?

Use a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```
private IEnumerator MoveUp(float distance, float duration) {
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position;
    Vector3 targetPosition = startPosition + new Vector3(0, distance, 0);
    float elapsed = 0;
    while (elapsed < duration) {
        yield return null; //wait until the next frame
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPosition, elapsed / duration);
    }
}

public void MoveUp() {
    StartCoroutine(MoveUp(50, 3));
}
```

A coroutine is a function that executes over time; you can use loops within a coroutine to do many kinds of animation, such as this simple position tween. Coroutines are a critical concept in Unity and you should take the time to learn them thoroughly if you're not already familiar with the topic.